# Split a group of people in half based on preference

Tags: python, combinations, split, preference

I'm a 3d Animation Tutor with very basic Python knowledge and have been bashing my head against a wall trying to code what I think could be a VERY beneficial script..
Any help would, including a simple point in the right direction would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my scenario: 
My class of 18 students is about to enter into the "group project" module. 
This year I would like to split the class in half to keep the projects more manageable and also to encourage healthy competition.
The students have already filled out surveys in which they annotated their preference for working with all the other students by giving each a number between 0 and 5.
My idea is that I can use these surveys to mathematically calculate the best possible split in terms of preference.

Now I've made a very basic start in CodeSkulptor - a browser based python emulator. 
In this prototype version I am starting with just 4 sample "students" - A, B, C and D. 
Each student has given their opinions of the others and to keep things simple, their opinion of themselves is all set at 0, (though this could just as easily be any value, since you can't NOT work with yourself..)

Here is my psuedocode:

1. Create empty set "students" that will contain all students, i.e. [A,B,C,D]
2. Create an empty set "combinations" that will be filled with all of the possible combinations, i.e [((A,B),(C,D)),((A,C),(B,D)),((A,D)(B,C))]
3. define a class containing preference information for each student, once all the possible combinations have been determined, this information will be used to calculate the combination with the overall highest "Happiness"/"Morale"..
4. Create a function that cycles through all the possible combinations, returning them as lists of lists which get added to the combinations set.
5. ( Not added yet ) Create a function that cycles through all the combinations in the set "combinations", and calculates overall "happiness" based off the preferences stored in the student class.
6. ( Not added yet ) Create a function that prints the combinations with the highest happiness.

In this case it should print:

```
print"A,B/C,D = 7"

print"A,C/B,D = 10"

print"A,D/B,C = 15"

print"Highest possible split is A,D/B,C with overall happiness of 15!"
```

I'm kind of embarrassed to show the WIP.. but here it is:

http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user17_EEvOfHGg7AAZt1w_1.py

Or for those that would rather stay on this page:

```
people = set([])
combinations = set([])

class person:
    def __init__(self, name, A = 3, B = 3, C = 3, D = 3):
        self.name = name
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.C = C
        self.D = D

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_A(self):
        return self.A

    def get_B(self):
        return self.B

    def get_C(self):
        return self.C

    def get_D(self):
        return self.D    

# make all the possible combinations
#def combine(people):
#combine any 2 given people into a new group

def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(r)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

####[A,B,C,D]
people.add(person("A", 0, 1, 2, 4))
people.add(person("B", 3, 0, 3, 4))
people.add(person("C", 1, 5, 0, 2))
people.add(person("D", 3, 3, 2, 0))

combinations(people,2)
```

The combinations function - I actually lifted straight off the itertools documentation page, but I'm not exactly sure if it's working or even if this is the best way to split the groups. 
I can't import itertools directly as CodeSkulptor only supports a few modules (math, random, time etc.). 
I tried using actual python but it functions a whole lot differently than I'm used to.
I have learned many things in my research, such as that calculating something like this may take years for the computer to go through the 24310 different split possibilities..
Another option would be for the code to just generate 100 random split possibilities at a time and I could keep track of the highest result each runthrough.
All in all, it's been a fun script to try and figure out - actually a little too fun. 
I can't physically tear myself away from it, even though I've stopped making actual progress.
So please, if someone could hint/show me where to go from here I would very much appreciate the help.

Cheers,

- Eli

Comment: Are you actually splitting the class in half (with groups of 9), or are you splitting the class into groups of two?

Comment: In half ( two groups of 9 ) This was mentioned in the second paragraph. and, no - ( (A,),(B,C,D) ) would be invalid

Comment: I suggest looking at a builtin module called itertools is a very helpful tool. I think you may find [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) in specific to be very helpful

Comment: I'd really recommend using the standard Python implementation. Doing it on CodeSkulptor will result in learning bad habits and duplicating a lot of standard library code. Just look at that big, confusing `combinations` function that could have been replaced with `from itertools import combinations`.

Comment: I agree, and have been attempting to transition into regular python. I have looked at itertools and was hoping to work out the underlying mechanics of itertools.combinations for myself before relying on it and perhaps taking it for granted. I can't say that I have figured it out just yet however...

Comment: Brute-forcing 24310 possibilities is entirely feasible. Unless CodeSkulptor is orders of magnitude slower than CPython, you shouldn't have a problem with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Completed

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
import string

    def get_maxhappiness(results):
        max_happiness = max(results)
        index = results.index(max_happiness)
    
        #Printing the result! (There may be more than one best result, but this will only show 1)
        print "Optimal Groups: Point value of",max_happiness,"\n",groups[index],"\n", anti_groups[index]
        results[index] = 0
        return results

def calculateHappiness(points,group):
    happiness = 0
    for i in range(len(group)):
        person_prefs = points[group[i]]
        others = group[i:] + group[:i]
        for other in others:
            happiness += person_prefs[other]
    return happiness



if __name__ == "__main__":
    people = string.letters[26:44]
    groups = list(combinations(people,9))
    anti_groups = [tuple(set(people).difference(set(x))) for x in groups]

    #Making fake results
    survey_results = dict()
    for person in people:
        results = dict(zip(people,np.random.randint(0,10,size=(len(people)))))
        results[person] = 0
        survey_results[person] = results

    #Printing Survey Results
    for name,values in survey_results.items():
        print "Student:", name, "has preferences:", values

    #Calculating happiness for every group
    results = []
    for i in range(len(groups)):
        results.append(calculateHappiness(survey_results,groups[i])+calculateHappiness(survey_results,anti_groups[i]))
    #Finding the largest happiness value
    top_n = 5
    while top_n > 0:
        results = get_maxhappiness(results)
        top_n -= 1
```

Yields:

```
...

Student: N has preferences: {'A': 5, 'C': 5, 'B': 0, 'E': 0, 'D': 3, 'G': 6, 'F'
: 8, 'I': 8, 'H': 3, 'K': 1, 'J': 4, 'M': 4, 'L': 9, 'O': 0, 'N': 0, 'Q': 3, 'P'
: 2, 'R': 2}
Student: Q has preferences: {'A': 9, 'C': 0, 'B': 3, 'E': 4, 'D': 3, 'G': 2, 'F'
: 2, 'I': 7, 'H': 5, 'K': 2, 'J': 3, 'M': 0, 'L': 9, 'O': 2, 'N': 5, 'Q': 0, 'P'
: 2, 'R': 0}
Student: P has preferences: {'A': 2, 'C': 3, 'B': 0, 'E': 9, 'D': 3, 'G': 6, 'F'
: 7, 'I': 1, 'H': 7, 'K': 9, 'J': 7, 'M': 4, 'L': 8, 'O': 2, 'N': 6, 'Q': 5, 'P'
: 0, 'R': 7}
Student: R has preferences: {'A': 5, 'C': 3, 'B': 7, 'E': 1, 'D': 5, 'G': 6, 'F'
: 1, 'I': 6, 'H': 9, 'K': 9, 'J': 3, 'M': 6, 'L': 8, 'O': 8, 'N': 5, 'Q': 1, 'P'
: 3, 'R': 0}
Optimal Groups: Point value of 709
('A', 'B', 'F', 'G', 'J', 'K', 'O', 'Q', 'R')
('C', 'E', 'D', 'I', 'H', 'M', 'L', 'N', 'P')
(x4)
```

Comment: Nice, this is a very efficient start. I had wondered about using dictionaries over defining a class. Good to know it's how others would do it. so this gets me all the way up to step 4. I will attempt to push on past here into the "possible combinations" step later on when I have access to proper python ( not codeskulptor )

Comment: So, I think the code in my post now works, but I would welcome people to test it out for accuracy because I haven't.

Comment: Wow! Thanks heaps :D I managed to get Python 2.7.5 up and running on my work computer without admin rights, but unfortunately it doesn't come packaged with numpy. Just working on getting that installed now.

Comment: Tested it, works perfect thanks! This is exactly what I needed. I'll test it tomorrow with my actual survey results.

Comment: Great. If you have any further questions about the code, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Just wondering how hard it would be to make it print several results? Lets say the 5 highest and their total happiness scores

Comment: could "max_happiness" instead .pop from max(results), and then I could continue to do this for the next best and so on?

Comment: What you can do is get the highest value index. change that to 0 after you grab it and then redo finding the max. The way I'm finding it uses the fact that the indices are matching the group indices. Not popping them out of hte list would be optimal.

Comment: @EliTucker I made the edit to print out several results in order of value, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I'm getting an error every time. "*** can't assign to function call(C:/Users/Eli/Desktop/groupSplitter2.py, line 11)"

which refers to the line:

    results(index) = 0

I think I know what it's trying to do here, but it doesn't seem to want to change the value of max_happiness for some reason I can't quite figure out.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's my fault. Indexing in python is with []'s not ()s. ()s are normally function calls.

Comment: awesome :) Works perfectly thanks! One last question and then I'll leave you alone ( probably... ): If I have a split already in mind, would there be a way of pushing that backwards through the script to find out the total happiness?

Comment: Run it through calculateHappiness (both the group and antigroup). calculateHappiness(survey_results,group) + calculateHappiness(survey_results, antigroup)

Comment: One year later, I have decided to try this process again, but this time I want to split the class into 3 groups. I looked back over the script, but due to the "anti_group" section, I'm certain it cannot do this in it's current state.. I'm going to try rebuilding it myself, but any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Cheers,